# OCR Web Validation using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, validation, limit, radiobuttonlist

I am a Computing teacher trying to stay one step ahead of my pupils whom are working on a assessment to with validating web forms using HTML and JavaScript. So far, I have managed to do the following but can no longer move forward:

```
<head>
<title>Exam entry</title>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

function validateForm() {
var result = true;
var msg="";
if (document.ExamEntry.name.value=="") {
msg+='You must enter your name';
document.ExamEntry.name.focus();
document.getElementById("name").style.color="#FF0000";
result = false;
}

if (document.ExamEntry.subject.value=="") {
msg+=' You must enter the subject';
document.ExamEntry.subject.focus();
document.getElementById("subject").style.color="#FF0000";
result = false;
}

if (document.ExamEntry.examnumber.value=="") {
msg+=' You must enter the examination number';
document.ExamEntry.examnumber.focus();
document.getElementById("examnumber").style.color="#FF0000";
result = false;
}

if(document.getElementById("examnumber").value.length!=4)
{
msg+='You must have exactly 4 digits in the examination number textbox';
document.ExamEntry.examnumber.focus();
document.getElementById("examnumber").style.color="#FF0000"
result = false;
}

function checkRadio() {
var user_input = "";
var len = document.ExamEntry.entry.length;
var i;
for (i=0;i< len;i++) {
    if (document.ExamEntry.entry[i].length.checked) {
        user_input = document.ExamEntry.entry[i].value;
        break;
    }
}

if (msg==""){
return result;
}
else
{
alert(msg);
return result;
}
}


function resetForm()
{
document.getElementById('ExamEntry').reset();
document.getElementById("name").style.color="#000000";

document.getElementById("subject").style.color="#000000";
document.getElementById("examnumber").style.color="#000000";
}



</script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Exam Entry Form</h1>
<form name='ExamEntry' method='post' action='success.html'>
<table width='50%' border='0'>
<tr>
<td id='name'>Name</td>
<td><input type='text' name='name' /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td id='subject'>Subject</td>
<td><input type='text' name='subject' /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td id='examnumber'>Examination Number</td>
<td><input type='text' name='examnumber'></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td id='entry'>Level of Entry</td>
<td><input type='radio' name='entry' value='gcse'>GCSE<BR></td>
<td><input type='radio' name='entry' value='as'>AS<BR></td>
<td><input type='radio' name='entry' value='a2'>A2<BR></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type='submit' name='Submit' value='Submit' onclick='return (validateForm());'></td>
<td><input type='reset' name='Reset' value='Reset' onclick=' (resetForm());'></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
</body>
```

What I want to do and what I am trying to do are two different things and it's now hit the point where I am banging my head against a brick wall.

What I WANT to do is be able to:

- **Extend the Javascript code to make sure that the user’s examination number is exactly 4 digits.**
- **Add a set of radio buttons to the form to accept a level of entry such as GCSE, AS or A2. Write a function that displays the level of entry to the user in an alert box so that the level can be confirmed or rejected.**

Can anyone help me before I totally lose the plot?

Comment: Why haven't you been able to, any errors or problems you may have found?
I'm trying to setup a jsFiddle with your code to test, but it's giving me errors: http://jsfiddle.net/c54fy/

Comment: First step: set a max length to <input type='text' name='examnumber' maxlength="4" />

Comment: I'd like to know if my answer helped at all!

Answer (score 1):

It's been a long time I have tried pure JS. It's a pleasure to try it out anytime though. So, someone's lukcy and I had some free time. I am a very tiny bit OCD when it comes to coding and I ended up cleaning a lot of your code, such as

1. Always enclose HTML attributes in double quotes - not a hard rule though.
2. Always close the input attributes - /> - not a hard rule though.
3. Define your elements and resue where needed in JS
4. Alwayst try and keep your JS separate from HTML - it's a good practice.
5. And follow the good old basics

As a result, here we go:

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lshettyl/g4KnF/12/)

HTML:

```
<h1>Exam Entry Form</h1>
<form name="ExamEntry" method="post" action="#">
    <table width="50%" border="0">
        <tr>
            <td id="name">Name</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="name" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td id="subject">Subject</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="subject" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td id="examnumber">Examination Number</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="examnumber" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td id="entry">Level of Entry</td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="entry" value="gcse" />GCSE<BR></td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="entry" value="as" />AS<BR></td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="entry" value="a2" />A2<BR></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" /></td>
            <td><input type="reset" name="Reset" value="Reset" onclick="resetForm();"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

JS:

```
var form = document.forms['ExamEntry'];
var iName = form.elements['name'];
var iSubject = form.elements['subject'];
var iExamNumber = form.elements['examnumber'];
var iLevel = form.elements['entry'];

function validateForm() {
    var result = true;
    var msg = "";
    if (iName.value=="") {
        msg+='You must enter your name';
        iName.focus();
        iName.style.color="#FF0000";
        result = false;
    } else if (iSubject.value=="") {
        msg+=' You must enter the subject';
        iSubject.focus();
        iSubject.style.color="#FF0000";
        result = false;
    } else if (iExamNumber.value=="" || !/^\d{4}$/.test(iExamNumber.value)) {
        msg+=' You must enter a valid examination number';
        iExamNumber.focus();
        iExamNumber.style.color="#FF0000";
        result = false;
    } else if(!checkEntry()) {
        msg+=' You must select a level';
        result = false;
    } else {
        var cfm = confirm("You have selected " + checkEntry() + ". Are you sure to punish yourself?");
        if (!cfm) {
            result = false;
        }
    }

    if (!result && msg != "") alert (msg);
    return result;
}

function checkEntry() {
    for (var i=0; i<iLevel.length; i++) {
        if (iLevel[i].checked) {
            return iLevel[i].value.toUpperCase();
        }
    }
    return false;
}

function resetForm() {
    form.reset();
    iName.style.color="#000000";
    iSubject.style.color="#000000";
    iExamNumber.style.color="#000000";
}

form.onsubmit = validateForm;
form.onreset = resetForm;
```

Comment: But how do I combine both the JavaScript and HTML into one so that I can run both as a webpage?

Comment: Like the way it is in here.

Answer (score 0):

First you added the function `checkRadio` inside of function `validateForm`

Also, this line

```
if(document.getElementById("examnumber").value.length!=4)
```

actually points to this piece of html

```
<td id='examnumber'>Examination Number</td>
```

The td element can't hold values... You need to change the line to this:

```
if (document.ExamEntry.examnumber.value.length!=4) {
```

This [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/678XN/22/) should help you out...